# Prove or Disprove: There exists a natural number $n$ for which if $x^{2} = 4 \pmod n$, then $x = 2 \pmod n $ for all integers $x$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So I am solving through an elementary number theory book and I can't seem to think of a good way to solve this question.

*"There exists a natural number $n$ for which if  $x^{2} = 4 \pmod n$, then $x = 2 \pmod n $ for all integers $x$"*

I can't think of an example of an n like this, and I couldn't find the answer on the internet. I tried solving a system of equations(bear in mind this is could be a completely wrong method):

$x^{2} - 4  = 0 \pmod n $

$x - 2  = 0 \pmod n $

By subtraction I got:

$x^{2} - x - 2  = 0 \pmod n $ (Corrected)

$(x+1)(x-2) = 0 \pmod n $

This leads nowhere close to proving or disproving an existence of such an n. Any clarification as to how to correctly tackle this problem(and why the method is correct if you could) would be highly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Well, note that $x^2=(-x)^2$ so look for an $n$ for which $2\equiv -2\pmod n$

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Remember $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$ has to be a field for that.

Comment: Just in case you're worried, *elementary* isn't supposed to be a synonym for *easy*

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Haha...indeed. I say that if it hard that means I am learning. Thank you

Comment: And your working is wrong; if you subtract those equations you get $x^{2} - x - 2  = 0 \pmod n $ not $x^{2} - x - 6  = 0 \pmod n $

Comment: @lulu I am not sure I am following. Could you please dumb it down a little bit for me lol The book I am learning on has not introduced negative mod notation so I am not entirely sure about it

Comment: @MichaelCohen True! Thank you!

Comment: @lulu Then, $n$ could only be $1$, $2$, or $4$.

Comment: @JB negative modulo are the same so for example $n-1 = -1 \mod n$  because $n-1 + 1 = n = 0 \mod n$. For modulo $5$ you can use $-2,-1,0,1,2$ as representatives instead of $0,1,2,3,4$ with the advantage being that multiplication keeps all the numbers small at the expense of keeping track of the sign.

Comment: All you need is one example of such an $n$.  Try $n=1,2$, as you suggest.

Comment: @lulu If i pick 1 or 2 as n then x^2 mod n can never be 4  because of how modulus works.. sooo it doesn't exist??

Comment: Not following.  $4\equiv 0\pmod 2$ and the only solution to $x^2\equiv 0\pmod 2$ is $x\equiv 0\pmod 2$, so $n=2$ works.

Comment: @lulu I mean in the original problem. If I picked a random x then for the set of n, x^2 (mod 1) = 0, or x^2 (mod 2) = 1 OR 0

Comment: $x^2\equiv 4 \pmod n$ just means that $n$ divides $(x^2-4)$.  Thus, $762^2\equiv 4 \pmod 2$, for example.

Comment: @lulu I see, maybe that is what I did not understand. Thank you so much for your time and patience in explaining :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solutions for $n$ are $1$ and $2$.

First, as lulu's comment pointed out, we only need to worry about those $n$ for which $2 \equiv -2 \pmod n$. This means that $n|(2-(-2))=4$, so $n$ could only be $1$, $2$, or $4$.

Clearly, $n=1$ works, because any two integers whatsoever are congruent mod $1$. Also, $n=2$ works, because if $x^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 2$, then $x^2$ is even, so $x$ is even, so $x \equiv 2 \pmod 2$.

However, $n=4$ does not work. For example, $4^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 4$, but $4 \not\equiv 2 \pmod 4$.

So, the statement "$\exists n \in \mathbb{N} \, \forall x \in \mathbb{Z} \, (x^2 \equiv 4 \pmod n) \implies (x \equiv 2 \pmod n)$" is true.

Comment: Thanks for helping! I don't see how 1 works.. Anything mod 1 is 0 and not 4 . So I see n as being higher than 4.

Comment: @JB $\bmod 1\,$ all congruences are true since $\,1\mid j-k\Rightarrow j\equiv k.\ $ In particular $\, x\equiv 2\pmod{\!1}\,$ for all $\,x\ \ $